# Scraping API - "Platform source was missing"

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-mumbai/ 
The first 20 cars and their data are in html, and are easily scraped.
I'm stuck on cars 21+ -- which are JSON. The format for the URL of each new page of 20 more cars is "http://www.carwale.com/webapi/classified/stockfilters/?city=1&kms=0-&year=0-&budget=0-&pn=2" with pn iteratively increasing.

[image]
[image]
I've tried:

```
i = 2  
while i in range(totalcars/20+1):
    link = 'http://www.carwale.com/webapi/classified/stockfilters/?city=2&kms=0-&year=0-&budget=0-&pn='+str(i)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(link)
    data = json.load(response)   
    print data
    i += 1
```

"HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request" is the response

Trying this link manually returns "Platform source was missing"

"http://www.carwale.com/webapi/" returns "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied."

What's the most pythonic and efficient method of accessing this data?

Comment: your url is not correct

Comment: the url is exactly what i get from clicking open in new tab on the file in picture above, which has worked in the past on json

Comment: Your right,  but for some reason its missing some parameter.  I'd look into the `$.GetNextPageData()` function to see if they're is something hidden with in your cookies that they're using to validate your request.

Comment: That's part of a Java package, correct? If so I unfortunately don't have any Java experience.

Comment: thats should be in their javascript/Jquery

Comment: found it. the snippet is                                                                           `$('.showMoreCars').on('click', function () {
            $.GetNextPageData();
            dataLayer.push({ event: 'showMoreCars', cat: 'UsedCarSearch', act: 'ShowMoreCars Clicked' });
        });`

Comment: Yeah thats where I saw it, if you walk that you should find it in there a slight discrepancy

Comment: @JonathanEpstein Have you found any solution ????

Comment: yes, I used Selenium to iteratively click on the $('.showMoreCars') button

Comment: @JonathanEpstein I have tried but not able to do this. can you please help me with the code if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to add this header, it worked for me.

> {"sourceid":"1"}